# QML how to use a dynamic topmargin correctly

Tags: qt, qml, margins

I want to enlarge or reduce a button depending on the presence of an icon. The buttons are in a rectangle and I would like to realize it with the top margin, because the buttons also have rounded corners and only the top corners should be visible.

The goal is a representation like this

[image]

If I set the topmargin fix to 10 it looks good

[image]

If I calculate the value depending on whether an icon is present, the buttons without icon are correctly displayed deeper, but the buttons with icon sit too deep

[image]

Like the picture before the topmargin for the icon buttons is 10 but they are moved lower.

Any idea - the code for display.qml is reduced and does not show all the properties. if they are needed i will add them.

FooterButton.qml

```
Rectangle {
    id: button
    property string p_identity
    property string p_icon
    property string p_source
    property string p_backgroundColor
    property int p_topmargin: 10
    height: 70
    width: 80
    Layout.leftMargin: 25
    Layout.topMargin: p_topmargin
    color: p_backgroundColor
    radius: 10
    border.color: "black"
    border.width: 0

    Connections { 
        target: m_screen; 
        onScreenChanged: { 
            p_icon = m_screen.getButtonIcon(p_identity)
            p_source = (!p_icon || p_icon.length === 0) ? "" : "image://iconprovider/" + p_icon)
           // p_topmargin = 10
            p_topmargin = (!p_icon || p_icon.length === 0) ? 45 : 10
        } 
    }
```

Footer.qml

```
Item {
    id: footer
    property string p_footerBackgroundColor: "yellow" //m_config.getColor(Colors.FooterBackground)
    property string p_buttonBackgroundColor: m_config.getColor(Colors.ButtonBackground)
    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; x: footer.x; y: footer.y; width: footer.width; height: footer.height; color: p_footerBackgroundColor
        RowLayout{ anchors.fill: parent
            FooterButton{ p_identity: "FB1"; p_backgroundColor: p_buttonBackgroundColor }
            FooterButton{ p_identity: "FB2"; p_backgroundColor: p_buttonBackgroundColor }
            FooterButton{ p_identity: "FB3"; p_backgroundColor: p_buttonBackgroundColor }
            FooterButton{ p_identity: "FB4"; p_backgroundColor: p_buttonBackgroundColor }
            FooterButton{ p_identity: "FB5"; p_backgroundColor: p_buttonBackgroundColor }
        }
    }
```

Display.qml

```
Item {
    id: display


    Header { x: 0; y: 0; width: display.width; height: p_headerHeight; visible: p_headerVisible; color: p_backgroundColor; p_buttonColor: p_buttonBackgroundColor  }
    Left { x: 0; y: p_headerHeight; width: p_borderWidth; height: p_contentHeight; color: "blue" }
    Right { x: display.width - p_encoderWidth; y: p_headerHeight; width: p_encoderWidth; height: p_contentHeight; p_color: "magenta" }
    Footer { x: 0; y: display.height - p_footerHeight; width: display.width; height: p_footerHeight; visible: p_footerVisible }
```

Comment: Not really sure I understand the purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just making sure you're not over-engineering your problem, but, I want to point out that the standard `Button` has both `icon` support and the ability to change the background to a rounded `Rectangle`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    footer: Frame {
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "yellow"
        }
        RowLayout {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            spacing: 20
            AppButton {
                //icon.source: "hammer.svg"
            }
            AppButton {
                //icon.source: "hammer.svg"
            }
            AppButton {
                icon.source: "hammer.svg"
            }
            AppButton {
                //icon.source: "hammer.svg"
            }
            AppButton {
                icon.source: "check.svg"
            }
        }
    }
}

// AppButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Button {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    background: Rectangle {
        color: pressed ? palette.mid : palette.button
        radius: 20
    }
    icon.source: "blank.svg"
    icon.width: 64
    icon.height: 64
}

// blank.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
</svg>

// hammer.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M29.64 25.462c-1.186-1.62-3.535-4.176-6.254-7.136-2.657-2.893-5.671-6.173-8.066-9.11a3.883 3.883 0 0 1-1.044-1.531 6.899 6.899 0 0 0-.215-1.271 3.427 3.427 0 0 1-.08-.348 7.985 7.985 0 0 1 3.153-1.61 25.43 25.43 0 0 1 4.095-.527l1.08-.043-1.14-1.239-.148-.035a24.293 24.293 0 0 0-5.123-.606A13.096 13.096 0 0 0 7.53 4.82c-.225.2-1.433 1.478-1.338 2.334.078.73-.212.949-.792 1.383a8.35 8.35 0 0 0-.558.444c-1.468-.125-1.92.252-3.014 1.16l-.39.32-.095.105a1.472 1.472 0 0 0-.277 1.24 7.214 7.214 0 0 0 2.294 3.029 2.25 2.25 0 0 0 2.404-.483 18.003 18.003 0 0 0 1.577-2.018 2.67 2.67 0 0 1 1.633-1.26 12.815 12.815 0 0 1 2.588.88c.11.046.2.077.277.104.05.018.111.032.116.036 4.108 5.004 6.896 8.936 8.93 11.807 1.401 1.976 2.413 3.404 3.3 4.412l.912 1.038a1.935 1.935 0 0 0 1.362.651l.078.001a1.939 1.939 0 0 0 1.334-.534l1.548-1.486a1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .22-2.52zM12.059 11.028l-.029.034c-.03-.012-.052-.018-.088-.033a10.285 10.285 0 0 0-3-.954 3.577 3.577 0 0 0-2.454 1.738 21.031 21.031 0 0 1-1.375 1.786c-.605.434-.936.519-1.313.338a6.931 6.931 0 0 1-1.792-2.446.85.85 0 0 1 .125-.305l.334-.275c1.045-.867 1.228-1.021 2.299-.933a1.02 1.02 0 0 0 .738-.247A7.72 7.72 0 0 1 6 9.337a2.27 2.27 0 0 0 1.186-2.288A3.785 3.785 0 0 1 8.19 5.571a12.232 12.232 0 0 1 7.706-2.565 20.9 20.9 0 0 1 2.624.178c-.523.076-1.076.173-1.614.298A9.024 9.024 0 0 0 13.34 5.3a1.176 1.176 0 0 0-.25 1.356 5.831 5.831 0 0 1 .19 1.1 3.345 3.345 0 0 0 .842 1.625 9.48 9.48 0 0 0-.994.683 7.036 7.036 0 0 0-1.068.964zm16.668 16.234l-1.547 1.485a.945.945 0 0 1-.678.256.924.924 0 0 1-.652-.312l-.912-1.038c-.853-.97-1.905-2.452-3.236-4.33-2.018-2.848-4.78-6.742-8.838-11.696a6.433 6.433 0 0 1 .875-.772 8.145 8.145 0 0 1 .964-.66l.09-.05C17.14 13 20.06 16.182 22.65 19.001c2.7 2.939 5.032 5.477 6.184 7.051a.923.923 0 0 1-.106 1.209z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>

// check.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M13.5 22.142L7.59 16.42l.636-.636L13.5 20.87 26.721 7.8l.637.637z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, I will try it out. But for the basic problem with the topmargin it will probably not matter if I take a button or a rectangle or?

Comment: Can you create a minimal repro - I cannot understand your problem fully from the description.

Comment: I have not done that yet, sorry. In your example it would only be necessary to add that in a signal / event the buttons without image have a topmargin of e.g. 50 and those with image of 10. In my case the topmargin of the buttons with image is then always much larger than 10.

Comment: The problem is it isn't clear to me why you want to do this. Perhaps if I understood more of what you're trying to achieve. The screenshots and the supplied code, unfortunately, haven't helped convey your problem. Therefore, I couldn't figure out what your fault is and what you want to be fixed.

Comment: The buttons should not show any rounding at the bottom, that's why I wanted to move them with a topmargin so far that they virtually slip out of the rectangle at the bottom. The buttons that have no icons should be displayed only half as a feedback that they can not be used. This is a request of the customer. If I give all buttons a topmargin 10 (second image) then everything looks good. If a signal comes and the icons are reloaded and the topmargin is recalculated the buttons with image slide much deeper although they get only topmargin of 10 (third image). And that I do not understand

Comment: I solved the problem anchors { top: parent.top; topMargin: 10 } are missing